# Upload files to firebase storage and use firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, firebase-storage

When I try to upload files to firebase storage and use firefox, I see that multiple POST attempts are made and finally I get `"Firebase Storage: Max retry time for operation exceeded, please try again."`. But it works perfect on chrome.
Any reason why? How can this be fixed?

**Edit: Added the code I used and the POST request sent in Firefox as seen the Network tab below.**

Here is code that I am using to store file to firebase storage, works perfectly fine in chrome but not if firefox, makes multiple post attempts in firefox and finally gives `storage/retry-limit-exceeded`:

```
this.storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
var fileMetaData = {
   contentType: 'application/pdf'
};
this.storageRef.child('6dc4389c5a0f3a5fc784d1132319622e/Policy.pdf').put(file, fileMetaData);
```

Here is the POST request as seen in network tab:
[image]
Here is screenshot of continuous set of POST requests that Mozilla sends before the retry limit exceeded:
[image]

The firefox version that I have is **48.0.2**

**Edit: Firebase Storage Upload works in Private browsing mode in Firefox. One thing to notice is is that `DNT` is also being sent in the request header in private browsing mode. It's strange. Here is the screenshot of the successful request sent:**
[image]

**Edit 23/09/2016: The request body is empty when uploading files through firefox when not incognito. Please see the below screenshot:**
[image]

Comment: Please include a minimal repro, version info, and all the things we would need to know to verify and troubleshoot a nuanced problem like this.

Comment: @Kato I have added the code and relevant screenshots and FF version.

Comment: Thanks Samar, great stuff. Could you try this in incognito? That will help us rule out plugins, caching, and other moving parts.

Comment: @Kato  Firebase Storage Upload works in Private browsing mode in Firefox. One thing to notice is is that DNT is also being sent in the request header in private browsing mode. Please see my updated question above.

Comment: So this sounds like a plugin issue--maybe an adblock tool, etc. What clued me in here was the fact that the requests were taking 0ms to 1ms to compete--they aren't even getting off the network at those speeds. If you continue to have issues, please show the contents of the "Response" tab for one of the POST requests and see if there are any errors logged in the JS console. : )

Comment: @Kato Thanks. But the thing is, this issue with Mozilla Firefox is not only at my end, but about 100 users (testers) in different countries. Hence, definitely not due to some kind of plugin, I have installed. Also, I have tested with a fresh install of Firefox. The question is, why all the users are facing the same issue with Firefox when not incognito. Definitely firefox internally is altering the POST request in some way, that there is no response from firebase server. As you see, the pre-flight request goes perfect with firebase but POST is rejected as soon as it connects to firebase.

Comment: @Kato I just reset my firefox (https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/refresh-firefox-reset-add-ons-and-settings?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=reset-firefox-easily-fix-most-problems) to remove all addons and extensions, still the issue doesn't resolve.

Comment: Hard to guess here, since the connection is not even leaving your computer. Contents of the "Response" tab and any console errors (or confirmation that there aren't any) would still be helpful

Comment: @Kato The Response tab is empty and there are no console errors.

Comment: Not going to be able to help here then until there are more clues.

Comment: Same here. No more clue needed, a lot was given by the op. Only a few words needed to describe the problem -- Firebase Storage Upload And Firefox No work. Been going on for a while and still no fix from Firebase :/

Comment: any news on that? Using Sentry to catch errors and it is happening in android with chrome too